# Self casting a void pointer to point to int in C program is it possible?

Tags: c, pointers, int, void

I was writing a program to dynamically generate arrays, just as an experiment to clear off rust , still a student and havent been doing C code for a while: See the block which is marked with "WORKING" comment in code below.

**Constraint : you have only one void pointer to point to user requested/generated type array(the array can be a float, int, double, char)**
you do not get to create pointers of any other type in main routine.

Is it possible to self cast a void pointer to (int *)

Here is some weird code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//prototypes
int* create_int_arr(int);

int main()
{
    int choice, arr_size;
    void* arr_ptr;
    printf("Please enter what kind of array you want?");
    printf("\nOptions are :");
    printf("\n1: int 2:float 3:char 4:double");
    scanf("%d",&choice );
    printf("\nHow many elements in the array do you want?");
    scanf("%d",&arr_size);
    switch(choice){
        case 1: printf("\nYou have chosen Integer array");
            arr_ptr =(int *) create_int_arr(arr_size);
            printf("\nThe array starts at %p",arr_ptr);
            break;
        case 2: printf("\nYou have chosen Float array");
            //create_float_arr();
            break;
        case 3: printf("\nYou have chosen a char array");
            //create_char_arr();
            break;
        case 4: printf("\nYou have chosen a double array");
            //create_double_arr();
            break;
        default:printf("\nYou have not chosen properly! Exiting!");
            return 0;
            break;
    }
    //arr_ptr = (int *)arr_ptr    <= does nothing FAIL! self cast
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<arr_size;i++)
    {
        //==========WORKING =============
        *(int*)arr_ptr = i;           //casting the void pointer to int to store values every time, would like to self cast the void pointer to int* permanently any way to do this?
                  //i know i can declare a new int pointer and cast the void* into int* but lets just say that was not an option for arguments sake

        printf("\n%d", *(int *)arr_ptr);
        //=================================
    }

    return 0;
}

int* create_int_arr(int size){
    int * ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    printf("\nThe array starts at %p",ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

Help me out pro ppl at C! :)

Comment: Of course `arr_ptr = (int *) arr_ptr` will not do anything, it's like doing `some_variable = some_variable` and expecting something to actually happen. The `arr_ptr` variable is of type `void *`, no amount of casting is going to change that, thats why you need to cast the pointer before accessing elements. If you don't want to cast every time you need to use it as an integer array, then add a new variable: `int *int_arr_ptr = arr_ptr;`

Comment: Your title is misleading, you are casting a `void` pointer to a pointer to `int`, not to an `int`

Comment: so basically you are saying self casting would not change the type declaration of a pointer @JoachimPileborg, is there some magical way to do that is what i am asking.

Comment: No, there is no such way to do this, C has static typing. Perhaps you tell us what you want to do with all that stuff.

Comment: not much like the program dynamically generate arrays of any type with the constraint of using only 1 void pointer or rather just one pointer in the main routine , to point to whatever array gets generated based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes void pointer can be typecasted.

While your are tying to assign & print the value, the base address is not incremented. Find the correction here

```
*(int*)(arr_ptr+i) = i; 
printf("\n%d", *(int *)(arr_ptr+i));
```

arr_ptr is a pointer, which holds only the base address.In your case, traverses from base address and assign the value.

Comment: try running the code and see for yourself! it still gives me correct sequence 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: @Dexobox Yes, because you're setting the 1. element (only) and printing it out in the same loop, you're not iterating over an array.

Comment: @nos dont really care about storing elements in the array , the main issue is i would like to be able to change the type of the pointer to point to int data permanently,or to basically change it into an int type pointer

Comment: @Dexobox You can't do that, C is statically typed. You can set another variable that means `please treat arr_ptr` as an `int*` , and then have everyone that wants to use `arr_ptr` contain the logic to cast `arr_ptr` to an `int*` when accessing it.

Comment: ok that makes a little sense , my goal here was to use one void pointer and was asking if i could change its type to an int pointer, a double pointer or a char pointer based on the user input/flow of the program, Guess Not! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your function already returns a `int*`, so just change the type of your pointer to `int*` and delete all the casts. A good C program should not contain casts but chose the right type for all variables from the start.

Then, effectively as mahendiran says, the `for`-loop is probably not what you want it to do. Just use `arr_ptr[i] = i;` to write `i` in the `i`th place of the array.

Comment: so i create NULL pointer for every type of array which i want to generate dynamically. Yes that is an option, what if it was not an option, say you had one pointer to point to any any type of array the program user requests to be created. forget about printing the array , thats a non issue, debug code to check things if they work.

Comment: arr_ptr[i]=i; gives       ../array.c:46:3: error: invalid use of void expression
   arr_ptr[i]=i; @Jens Gustedt

Comment: @Dexobox, yes sure, as I said this only works if you chose the correct type for the pointer.

Comment: And for your "universal" use, your `create_int_array` function is then completely useless. Just use `malloc(sizeof(int[size]))`, `malloc(sizeof(float[size]))`, whatever for your individual cases.

Comment: agreed , i was just practising making functions that could return pointers

Answer (score 0):

The casting in your program is not correct.  malloc() returns a void * pointer which needs to be cast to int * as shown below.

```
int* create_int_arr(int size){
            int * ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
            printf("\nThe array starts at %p",ptr);
            return ptr;
}
```

The return value from create_int_array should be saved in an int * ptr.  In the example it is being saved in arr_ptr which is a void * causing the int * typing to be removed.  the c language does not provide a mechanism for remembering what type a variable was cast to in the past.  All it knows is the type of reference currently being performed.